# Return a new object with some extra properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, immutability, reducers

I have an objects

```
usersById: {
  1: { name: 'John' },
  2: { name: 'Michelle' },
  ...
}
```

I want to return the same object, but first populate the object at id=2 with a new property `age`, but sticking to immutability.

I would guess it would be something like

```
return {
  ...usersById,
  ...usersById[2].age = 40
}
```

but I receive an error `In this environment the sources for assign MUST be an object. This error is a performance optimization and not spec compliant`.

Alternatively, I would guess it should be something like

```
return Object.keys(usersById).map(userId => {
  if (userId === 2) {
    return {
      ...usersById[2],
      ...age = 40
    }
  }
  return usersById[userId]
})
```

but it returns an array and not an object.

Comment: Map always returns an array, as it's an array method.

Comment: I know, but isn't `reduce` also an array method that could return an object with `arr.reduce((accumulator, item) => { ... }, {})`?

Comment: It's not a tautology. Array methods do not always return an array. I shouldn't have used that as an explanation.

Answer (score 7):

You've got the right idea but the wrong syntax. Try this instead:

```
return {
  ...usersById,
  2: {
    ...usersById[2],
    age: 40
  }
}
```

Or if the key is dynamic, you can do this:

```
let key = 2;
return {
  ...usersById,
  [key]: {
    ...usersById[key],
    age: 40
  }
}
```

Comment: @Jamgreen Glad I could help :)

Comment: I'm sorry to stick into here, but why not just try usersById[2].age = 40; return usersById; ? The solution in this answer returns array with original object as first element, and updated sub-object as second element. I'm sorry, but I don't understand something here and would appreciate if you explain it broader... Thanks!

Comment: @GSazheniuk Because that would technically be an impure operation. The benefits of immutability are too many to get into here but just know that this is done in order to avoid mutations.

Comment: @MikeC So basically this is to keep original object (usersById) immutable, and at the same time return an updated object? Ok, if that's the point - I got it. Thank you for explanation! :)

Comment: @GSazheniuk You got it!

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own function to return same object with populated values

Simple example:

```js
var usersById =  {
  1: { name: 'John' },
  2: { name: 'Michelle' },
}

usersById = oneLevelDeepAssign(usersById,2,{age:21})


function oneLevelDeepAssign(object, key, objectToAssign){

  return Object.assign({},object,{[key]:Object.assign({},object[key],objectToAssign)})

}

console.log(usersById);
```